# Tomcat6 Duplicate Deployment

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, web-deployment

I am facing the issue of Tomcat double deployment. I have read the context information available on Apache site, and well, lets just say, it left me confused.

**Environment** :

1. Tomcat 6 with 5 webapps
2. Each webapp has a context.xml in its META-INF folder
3. The context.xml stores database information, crucial for the webapp to function

**Requirement** :
One out of the 5 webapps needs to be made a default webapp. So, instead of going to `http://localhost:8080/WebAppA` it should work with only `http://localhost:8080`

**Current Methodology** :

1. Create a context inside tomcat/conf/server.xml
2. Copy the contents of WebAppA/META-INF/context.xml file to the context created inside tomcat/conf/server.xml

> ```
> <Context path="" docBase="/home/tomcat/webapps/WebAppA" debug="0" reloadable="true">
>     <Resource name="jdbc/WebAppA" ... />
> </Context>
> ```

**Problem With Current Methodology** :

1. WebAppA as well as some of the other webapps seem to be getting deployed multiple times (two times)
2. A folder called ROOT is created in tomcat/webapps folder

I have looked through some of the proposed solutions on the internet, but they don't work for me.

1. I cannot rename my default webapp ROOT.war
2. I cannot turn off autodeploy on any of the webapps

Any pointers on this will be much apprecaited.

Cheers,
Rohitesh

Answer (score 2):

The double deployment is probably from having the context defined inside of your web app AND inside of your war.

I have deployed wars at the root context in two ways, in the past:

(1) Just unzip (or explode) the war into a *folder* named ROOT in the webapps directory.

(2) Creating/editing the context file at conf/Catalina/host/context.xml

In both cases I do NOT include a context file in the war, and do NOT include it in server.xml.  Hope that helps.